# List logged in users in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code, razor-pages

I'm making a chat application in web api using ASP.NET, SignalR, Razor Pages in C# in Visual Studio Code. I have a registration/login page and I want to list the logged in users. Here is my code in **Index.cshtml** site, where the user logging in:

```html
 public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        var acc = login(account.Username, account.Password);
        if (acc == null)
        {
            Msg = "Invalid";
            return Page();
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("username", acc.Username);
            return RedirectToPage("Wilcome");
        }
    }
```

I wondered to make the code inside the `else`, but don't really know, how to add the every logged users into a list, and after just write into the page this list.

Comment: Web applications are stateless by definition. You would need to define logic for what it means to be "logged in". Maybe has an active connection via SignalR? Either way the code snippet above does not begin to cover it. As a side note you should not store authentication information in the Session, that is bad practice.

Comment: You need a HostedService that keeps this information and can be accessed from the pages. That's where all the simplistic SignalR examples fail to deep dive.